# Kafka partition data repeated consumption

Tags: apache-kafka

Since the original number of copies of all topics is 1, high availability cannot be achieved. After changing the number of copies to 2, one of the partition lag suddenly became very large at a certain moment, and finally found that the partition data was repeatedly consumed

kafka information

- version : 2.4.1
- number of nodes : 5
- number of partitions : 32

Accident scene information

- [Consumption Group Offset Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cISN.png)
- [Monitoring Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BslZp.png)

My Problem Locating Process

1. Checked the logs of the consumer and kafka broker, and found no suspicious logs
2. Check whether the broker state has changed
3. Check the storage time of the offset, the default is 7 days after version 2.x
4. Check whether the consumed offset is submitted to the broker

What caused it, and is it related to the change in the number of copies?

Comment: Changing replication does not affect lag since you're not consuming from different brokers for any partition

Comment: This did not happen before the number of replicas was changed

Comment: There is no delay in the data, and the data in a certain partition is consumed repeatedly after more than ten hours

Comment: Okay, well, that has nothing to do with replication factor. There are other reasons for lag, is all I'm saying. For example, maybe the leader of the partition changed and you're not able to connect with that one (but can for the other), and after "10 hours", the leader changed for some reason, allowing your app to consume again

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also believe that it has nothing to do with the copy change. The most doubtful thing is that there is no log to record the occurrence of the exception, which makes it difficult to troubleshoot. Now my solution is to first roll back the number of copies and observe whether it recurs

Comment: This problem occurs every ten hours, but the partition will be different every time

Comment: Do you not have a log4j.properties file? You can add debug/trace logging... I suggest describing the topic and looking what leader each partition has, and seeing if your problem is with a specific broker